# PHP cron removing a day from subscription

Tags: php, mysql, cron, membership, subscription

So this is my cron.php, which was used for resetting viewed youtube videos every 24 hours. I'm trying to achieve where ptime gets a point deducted every 24 hours if it's greater than 0. Maybe I'm totally doing it wrong, but any advice or reference would help me immensely.

```
    <?
    include("database.php");
    if(!(@mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass") && @mysql_select_db("$tablename"))) {?>No connection...<? }

    mysql_query("UPDATE `cron` SET `time`= unix_timestamp(data_format(data_add( now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') WHERE `name`=`day`");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `visits`");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `surfed`");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `viewed`");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `premium` SET `ptime`=`ptime`- 1 WHERE `ptime` > '0'");
    ?>
```

this is my cron datatable

SQL result

Host: localhost
Database: view4coins
Generation Time: Feb 09, 2012 at 05:43 PM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.4.9 / MySQL 5.5.20-log
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `cron` LIMIT 0, 30 ;
Rows: 3
name    time
day     1328836267
hour    1297720800
week    1297900801

*This is a template script I purchased off codecanyon that the owner no longer gives support on*

Answer (score 0):

I guess field `time`has unixtime in it, so it's more easier to update time directly with mysql than calculate it by hand.

```
    UPDATE `cron` 
    SET `time`= unix_timestamp( 
               date_format(date_add( now(), interval 1 hour), '%Y-%m-%d') 
    ) 
    WHERE `name`='hour'  and  date_add( now(), interval 1 hour) <= time

    UPDATE `cron` 
    SET `time`= unix_timestamp( 
               date_format(date_add( now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') 
    ) 
    WHERE `name`='day'  and  date_add( now(), interval 1 day) <= time

    UPDATE `cron` 
    SET `time`= unix_timestamp( 
               date_format(date_add( now(), interval 1 week), '%Y-%m-%d') 
    ) 
    WHERE `name`='week'  and  date_add( now(), interval 1 week) <= time
```

Comment: what about my datatable? remove the useless rows? (day, hour, week)?

Comment: also how do I test this? just change intervals from 1 day to 1 minute?

Comment: i've updated my answer - hope it'll be more clear. to test - yes, if you dont have a test database, just change intervals

Comment: the only thing is my PHP doesn't recognize `cron` as a table it looks like. UPDATE,SET, and WHERE are values to pull from a table i thought? (i'm no expert.. still learning from lynda and php.net manual)